# Making objects disappear based on light in blender

Tags: blender

Is it possible to make an object appear and disappear based on a light source like a sun? For example, a sphere with sunlight hitting half of it. Is it possible to make the lit area invisible and the shadowed area remain visible?

Comment: Kind of like [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/117347/935)?

Comment: yep thanks pretty much what i wanted